# How to get Swagger UI's Parameter to be Dropdown menu instead of Text Input

Tags: java, rest, jersey, swagger

I am using swagger to display my RESTApi, one parameter of an API takes string as input and convert it to enum value. Is there any way to display a drop-down menu on the Swagger UI instead of having a text input field so that users can only select the string values within the enum value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is to use [`allowableValues`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiParam.html#allowableValues()) in the `@ApiParam` annotation.

The demo showing the result:

http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/findPetsByStatus

Check out `pet/findByStatus`, it's not a dropdown but input is limited in
the multi-select box.

Comment: Sadly those links are now dead.

Comment: unfortunately there is no such alternative in openapi.

Comment: @saran3h you can actually via https://stackoverflow.com/a/73607986/1132056

Answer (score 11):

you can display dropdown using following code of swagger. You have to use **enum**.
e.g. if you want to take gender as input then there can be three possible values

> - male, female, other

```
-name: "gender"
          in: "query"
          type: "string"
          enum: [ "male", "female", "other"]
          description: "Enter user gender here."
          required: true
```

Comment: How to get Swagger UI's key to be Dropdown menu instead of Text Input

Answer (score 6):

You can directly use enum instead of String parameter as a API parameter.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void test(EnumTest enum) {
    // body
}
```

EnumTest.java

```
public enum EnumTest {

    One("One"),
    Two("Two");

    private String str;

    EnumTest(String str){
       this.str = str;
    }

    public String getStr() {
       return str;
    }
```

}

Comment: Does not produce a drop-down menu in the swagger UI...

Comment: @DavidS, which version of swagger you are using?

Answer (score 1):

with swagger 3(OAS) you can achieve that with below code

```
public class TestController{

@Operation(
      tags = "APIs",
      summary = "Find XYZ",
      parameters = {
            @Parameter(
            in = ParameterIn.QUERY,
            name = "id",
            schema = @Schema(allowableValues = { "value1", "value2",
                "value3", "value4" }),
            description ="description ")
      })
     
@GetMapping
public Flux<Response> getResponse(@RequestParam(value = "id") Optional<String> id){

}    
}
```

So if you run this you will have value1, value2, value3, value4 as dropdown value for id field in swagger

Comment: Works fine with springdoc-openapi-ui, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not work for me. The simplest way to add a dropdown list in Swagger is to update the swagger.json file.

```
"parameters": [
                {
                    "name": "status",
                    "in": "query",
                    "type": "string",
                    "default": "available",
                    "enum": [
                                "active",
                                "inactive",
                                "available"
                    ],
                    "required": true
                }     
            ],
```

Note: I'm using swagger version 2.0

[image]