# Springfox to OpenAPI Springdocs migration: @ApiImplicitParam(allowMultiple=true) equivalent?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox

I'm migrating from springfox to OpenAPI springdocs and I have to replace

```
@ApiImplicitParam(allowMultiple=true)
```

`@ApiImplicitParam` is replaced with `@Parameter`, but what is the OpenAPI springdoc equivalent to `allowMultiple=true`?

---

Reference: https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

Comment: I had similar issue and accepted answer to this question pointed me in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62527254/how-does-open-api-3-0-support-a-single-query-param-key-with-multiple-values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below approach

Before

> @ApiImplicitParam(value="Filter by type", allowableValues="typeA,typeB,typeC",
> allowMultiple=true)

After

> @Parameter(description = "Filter by type",
> schema=@Schema(type="string",
> allowableValues={"typeA","typeB","typeC"}, defaultValue = "typeA"))

Comment: Where is the example about "allowMultiple=true"?

Comment: It was about `true` only, corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from what @tomjankes put in his comment to the question -> the answer is to add `explode=Explode.TRUE`. Here's an example piece of code that worked for me:

```
@Parameters({
    @Parameter(name = "sort", **explode = Explode.TRUE**, schema = @Schema(type = "string"), in = ParameterIn.QUERY, description = "Sort setting in the format of: property(,asc|desc). Default sort order is ascending. Multiple sort settings are supported.") 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the array param as the example below:

```
@Parameter(array=@ArraySchema(schema = @Schema()))
```